# Error de animación CSS en botón

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Tengo un problema con una animación de un elemento en mi sitio web. Es un botón que tiene una animación al cargar la página, donde se mueve de derecha a izquierda hasta quedar en su sitio.

```css
.boton {
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-name: slidein;
animation-delay: 0s;
}
@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

Ahí está el código de la animación. El problema es que esta animación ocurre al cargar la página, y resulta que antes de realizar la animación completa, la realiza pero hasta cierto punto, se vuelve hacia atrás y entonces sí la realiza como corresponde, lo cual da una mala primera impresión del sitio. Es como que "da saltitos" antes de realizar la animación completa, seguramente porque el sitio está recién cargando.

Busqué mucho en internet, y no supe encontrar una respuesta a esta clase de problema. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

La página está siendo construida con Wordpress y Divi.

Pueden revisar directamente el problema que ocurre viendo la página web. Ojo, que no siempre ocurre, hay que recargarla para ver bien en caso de que no se note a la primera.

jyjadministradores.cl

De antemano gracias

Comment: podrías mostrar un ejemplo de como quieres que sea tu botón?

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba con Javascript cuándo se ha cargado toda la página y, llegado ese momento, añádele una clase CSS con la animación al elemento (o elementos) que quieras:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {    
    document.querySelector('.button').classList.add('animation');
  }
}
```

```css
.animation {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from { margin-left: 100%; }
  to   { margin-left: 0%; }
}
```

```html
<div><button type="button" class="button">Botón</button></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar de esa manera